# update view_count col in database, laravel, vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

I am trying to update `view_count` column on every `@click`. but couldn't figure out the right way of it.

First made the controller --resources and fetch datas via api.

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::all();

    return response()->json([
        "articles" => $articles
    ], 200);
}

public function show($id)
{
    $article = Article::whereId($id)->first();

    return response()->json([
        "article" => $article
    ], 200);
}
```

also set the update function too.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $view = Article::find($id);
    $view->update($request->where("view_count"));
    return response()->json(["message" => "view_count updated"]);
}
```

I set the api routes:

```
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('/articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('/articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@update');
```

And finally in Vue.js

```
<p class="button">
   <i @click.prevent="count" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
</p>

data(){
    return {
        view: 0,
    };
},
methods: {
    count: function(){
        axios.post("/api/articles" + this.item.id).then(response => {
            this.view++;
        })
        window.location.href = "pages/" + this.item.id

    }
}
```

it's counting but not update the col. also, when I refresh the page of course it will start to count from 0... it's not really efficient way to it. what is the best and right way to do it?

Thank you.

*Not:* By the way I am fetching and iterating api in the parent component:

```
<div class="listWrap" :key="item.id" v-for="item in filterArticles">
   <list :item="item" />
</div>
```

Comment: where you are declaring your item object, please?

Comment: in the parent I am iterating the articles... and passing it to child component. I updated the question and added it at bottom. @Thamerbelfkih

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your workflow to update views is wrong.

first, we should change our uri method of the update method to `GET` like below :

```
Route::get('/articles/update/{id}', 'ArticlesController@update');
```

then, our `update` method within `ArticlesController` to increment `view_count` value:

```
public function update(int $id)
{
   // i have changed the $view by $article
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->view_count++;
    $article->save();
    return response()->json(["message" => "view_count updated", 201]);
}
```

and within our Vue component, we should update the URI of the update method and the HTTP method name because we should use the same HTTP verb in both client and server sides.

```
    <p class="button">
       <i @click.prevent="count" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </p>

    <script>
    export default {
// as you are using parent/child relationship betwen components, you should use props.
        props: { item: Object },
        data(){
            return {
                view: 0,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            count: function(){
                axios.get(`/api/articles/update/${this.item.id}`).then(response => {
                    this.view++;
                })
                window.location.href = "pages/" + this.item.id;
            }
        } 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: okay, you are life saver. it's working like a magic. the only thing I don't understand is why we use api path like this; `axios.get(`/api/articles/update/${this.item.id}`)`

Comment: first make this response as correct answer, please. about the api path because we should send, vue instance resolve the domaine path